# how i can know which site collection the managed property (inside the Query builder) belong to

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, content-query-web-part, administration

i am working on sharepoint server 2013. and i want to define a new Result Source. so i went to "Central administration" >> "Managed Services" >> "Search service" >> "Result Sources".
then i created a new Result source, and i open the Query builder. now inside the query builder i find a managed property named "Wiki Category" as follow:-

[image]

but i am a bit confused on which site collection this WikiCategory belongs to ? as in my case i have one web application and this web application contain 6 site collections, and 2 site collections are of type Enterprise Wiki. so how i can know the site collection the WikiCategory belongs to? as i have multiple site collections, and i am defining the Query at the Search Service level, which is on top of all the site collections?? or this WikiCategory will refer to multiple site collections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed Properties are agnostic of Site Collections. So "Wiki Category" does not belong to any site collection. They are bound to Crawled Properties that are either "out of the box" or created as the result of creating Site and List columns and then crawling the content. The only way to ensure that the Wiki Category you seek is from a specific site or site collection is to add an additional query modifier that is unique to the site or site collection.

Managed Properties created at the SSA level are available Farm wide, at the Site Collection Level, they are available for the whole Site Collection, at the Site level they are for just that site. BUT, they are still part of the index, which is farm wide...depending on your SSA topology.

Comment: so when i write some thing as follow inside my Search Service Query builder <<WikiCategory<>"123">> so this WikiCategory will be used to filter all the underlying site collections ???

Comment: Depending on how your search service application, yes. Search results come from the items you have access to across the entire farm unless you modify the query by constraining the results to the Site Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Since it was created on the SSA level, this property refers to multiple site collections. You have another option to create a managed property on the site collection level and map it to that field and you use it on the site collection level.

Comment: so you mean the WikiCategory i have selected inside the SSA Query builder will refer to all the WikiCategorys inside the site collections ?

Comment: yeah, this column belong to an OOTB content type and it is the same content type used by any site collection using wiki pages

Comment: You are suggesting that the Site Collection Managed Property will only contacting results from that site collection and that is incorrect.